# Google app engine PHP SDK not working locally

Tags: google-app-engine

I am currently trying out the Google App Engine for PHP on my local development environment. So far, I have been following the instructions at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/helloworld in order to just test out a small app to get used to how the SDK works. However, when I get to the point of loading the test web server using the SDK, I get an error trying to load localhost:8080

The error:

WindowsError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ammar\google_appengine\lib\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 1302, in communicate
    req.respond()
  File "C:\Users\Ammar\google_appengine\lib\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 831, in respond
    self.server.gateway(self).respond()
  File "C:\Users\Ammar\google_appengine\lib\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 2115, in respond
    response = self.req.server.wsgi_app(self.env, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Users\Ammar\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\wsgi_server.py", line 250, in **call**
    return app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\Ammar\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\request_rewriter.py", line 311, in _rewriter_middleware
    response_body = iter(application(environ, wrapped_start_response))
  File "C:\Users\Ammar\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\php\runtime.py", line 133, in **call**
    cwd=self.config.application_root)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in **init**
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 948, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)

Answer (score 0):

How does the execution arguments look like? I had the same problem and I've work-around it by invoking **appserver** from within the **application** folder. In other words,

Instead of:

```
C:\Users\testing>gae\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=php/php-cgi.exe hello
```

I've used:

```
C:\Users\testing\hello>..\gae\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=..\php/php-cgi.exe .
```

Comment: Thanks, I invoked the appserver from the application and it worked fine